# microservices spring cloud, security, oauth2, Netflix OSS @EnableOAuth2Resource not exist in spring security 1.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, microservices

I use this tutorial [http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2015/04/27/building-microservices-part-3-secure-APIs-with-OAuth](http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2015/04/27/building-microservices-part-3-secure-APIs-with-OAuth/)/  to create organized webservices project based on Netflix OSS by using the following technologies spring cloud, boot, security, oauth2.

I'm using spring security 1.1 and I see annotation @EnableOAuth2Resource not exist in the spring security 1.1 what I should do?

Maven Dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>auctionblox</groupId>
<artifactId>auth-microservice</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <!-- Stand-alone RESTFul application for testing only -->
    <start-class>io.pivotal.microservices.services.Main</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash; Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Data common components -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Testing starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Data JPA Repository support -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Eureka service registration -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- In-memory database for testing/demos -->
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: what is spring security 1.1? Share your dependencies setup

Comment: @bilak I mean spring-cloud-security-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar. I updated project description and add dependencies

Answer (score 0):

use [@EnableResourceServer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.html) instead of `@EnableOAuth2Resource`

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot 1.2 we had to use Spring Cloud Security for the @EnableOAuth2Resource annotation. While, with Spring Boot 1.3 the Spring Cloud dependency can be removed and the annotation replaced with @EnableResourceServer annotation from Spring Security OAuth2.

For more details: https://spring.io/blog/2015/11/30/migrating-oauth2-apps-from-spring-boot-1-2-to-1-3#resource-server